# Parameterizing a proposition over other parameterized propositions of unknown arity in Coq

Tags: polymorphism, coq, decidable, parameterized-types

I want to define a parameterized proposition `decidable` that talks about the decidability
of other parameterized propositions. To take a common example, `even` is a parameterized proposition that takes 1 parameter of type `nat`, and it is decidable. `lt` is a parameterized proposition that takes 2 parameters of type `nat`, and it is also decidable. I want `decidable` to be such that `decidable even` and `decidable lt` are both provable propositions.

The main difficulty in definining `decidable` is specifying its type. It must accept any parameterized proposition of type `A -> B -> C -> ... Z -> Prop`, where A...Z are types and their total number is arbitrary.

Here's my first attempt:

```
Inductive decidable { X : Type } ( P : X ) : Prop :=
| d_0 : X = Prop -> P \/ ~ P -> decidable X P   
| d_1 : forall ( Y Z : Type ), ( X = Y -> Z ) 
  -> ( forall ( y : Y ), decidable Z ( P y ) )
  -> decidable X P.
```

I thought it should be OK to use `P \/ ~ P` as a premise in `d_0` because Coq would be smart enough to figure out that `P : Prop`, given the prior premise `X = Prop`. It's not.

So right now I can't find any way around spelling out the whole ugly thing: if I want to say that some `P : A -> B -> C -> ... Z -> Prop` is decidable, it must be written `forall ( a : A ) ( b : B ) ( c : C ) ... ( z : Z ), P a b c ... z \/ ~ P a b c ... z`. Ugh.

But maybe I'm missing something. Maybe there's some neat trick I've overlooked due to my rudimentary knowledge of Coq polymorphism.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Even.
```

You'll need a heterogeneous list of types. It only contains types but the types may be from different universes.

```
Inductive list : Type :=
  | nil : list
  | cons : Type -> list -> list.
```

This function takes a list of sets and returns the type of the predicates that vary over these sets. I don't know how to generalize this function to accept any list of sorts (Prop, Type 1, Type 2, ...).

```
Fixpoint predicate (l1 : list) : Type :=
  match l1 with
  | nil => Prop
  | cons t1 l2 => t1 -> predicate l2
  end.

Eval simpl in predicate (cons bool nil).
Eval simpl in predicate (cons bool (cons nat nil)).
```

This function takes a list of sets and a predicate that varies over these sets, and asserts that the predicate is decidable.

```
Fixpoint decidable (l1 : list) : predicate l1 -> Prop :=
  match l1 with
  | nil => fun p1 => p1 \/ ~ p1
  | cons t1 l2 => fun p1 => forall x1, decidable l2 (p1 x1)
  end.

Eval simpl in decidable (cons nat nil) even.
Eval simpl in decidable (cons nat (cons nat nil)) le.
Eval simpl in decidable (cons nat (cons Prop (cons Set (cons Type nil)))).
```